# TeXiFy IDEA: is there a shortcut to open the PDF without compiling?

Tags: texify-idea

I have a huge project, with many source files and their PDF versions.

When I start the IDE (Intellij IDEA), I'd like to be able to open the PDF version of a TeX file **without** having to recompile it. Recompiling would take some time and use CPU/memory resources to produce an already available file.

For now, I open the directory `out`, look for the file and double-click it. Not an easy task...

Is there a keyboard shortcut or even a menu option to open the PDF version of the source currently in edition?

I'd expect the *forward search* (`Ctrl-Alt-Shift-.`) to open the PDF file if is wasn't already open.

**IDE**:

IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Community Edition)

- Build #IC-223.8214.52, built on December 20, 2022
- Linux 5.10.0-20-amd64
- Current Desktop: GNOME

**TeXiFy**: version 0.7.25.1

Comment: it would certainly help if you could mention which IDE you actually use (texify it is not, that is a tool to compile).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: correct! I assumed TeXiFy was an exclusive tools to IntelliJ IDEA. I see now my mistake!

Comment: It's not there by default. You have to go to `Settings` -> `External Tools` and add a new entry. Then, set `Program:` to whichever application you use to open your PDFs, and set `Arguments:` to `$FileNameWithoutExtension$.pdf`. It will then appear in `Tools` -> `External Tools` menu, which you can assign a shortcut to.

Comment: @Celdor, this works just fine for me! Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

I did just like suggested by @Celdor in his comment:

> It's not there by default. You have to go to `Settings -> External Tools` and add a new entry. Then, set Program: to whichever application you use to open your PDFs, and set Arguments: to `$FileNameWithoutExtension$.pdf`. It will then appear in `Tools -> External Tools` menu, which you can assign a shortcut to.

Minor modification: I set the working directory to `$ProjectFileDir$/out` since my PDFs go to a separate directory.